# Partition of multisets of polynomials

Tags: np-complete, polynomials, partition-problem

Problem: Given a multiset S of irreducible polynomials in Z[x], say YES if S can be partitioned into two nonempty multisets A and B such that both the product of all the elements of A and the product of all the elements of B are polynomials with non-negative coefficients. Say NO otherwise.
Is this problem solvable in polynomial time ? Is it Np-complete ?

Comment: A heuristic that alas fails on some problem instances:  Let $r_1<r_2<\dots<r_m$ be the real roots of the polynomials, in increasing order.  Note that the sign of each polynomial is constant over $(r_i,r_{i+1})$.  Pick arbitrary rational values $c_0,\dots,c_{m+1}$ such that $c_0<r_1<c_1<r_2<\dots<r_m<c_{m+1}$.  Now find a way to partition $S$ into two multisets so that the product of polynomials in each multiset, when evaluated at every $c_i$, yields a non-negative number.  This is a linear algebra problem over $GF(2)$.  Finally, check whether this partition solves your original problem.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414227/partition-of-multisets-of-polynomials